# VueJS: Dynamic Class Binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue -V -- 3.0.5.

I have a component `Cube.vue` in which I'm trying to set a blue or green class to a child element dynamically.

I've created the component and have it imported into a specific page but I can't get the `or` to work correctly.

```
<template>
  <div :class="$style.cubeInner">
    <div class="cube" :class="{ 'cube--blue': isBlue ? 'cube--green': isGreen }">
      <div v-for="side in cubeside" :class="side.class" :key="side.id"></div>
    </div>
  </figure>
</template>
```

And here is my export

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Cube: 'cube',
      isBlue: Boolean,
      isGreen: Boolean,
    };
  }
};
```

I import into another component and render it via `<cube-hover></cube-hover>`. My question is do I need to set a `prop` or a `data()` for `isBlue` to be true or false? I can't seem to target the child since the entire component is being imported.

Basically, I can't target that nested `<div>`, it just adds the class to the parent. And I want to add `'cube--blue'` or `'cube--green'` to specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

Put the boolean into a data field, and then the condition check into a computed function.

## ...updated to add context

```
export default {
    data: () => {
        ...
        isBlue: Boolean,
        isGreen: Boolean,
    },
    computed: 
        isBlue() {
            if (is it blue?) return true;
            return false;
        },
        isGreen() {
            if (is it green?) return true;
            return false;
        }
}

<template>
    ...
    <div class="cube" :class="{ isBlue ? 'cube--blue' : 'cube--green': isGreen }">
    <!-- I think this is where you went wrong: "'cube--blue': isBlue ? 'cube--green': isGreen" see note -->
</template>
```

## note

You have a "?" separating your classes which should either be a comma, or you are trying to do a ternary operation. Comma separation could possibly apply both at once and I suspect you don't want that. Or if you are trying to do conditional class assignment:

## Fix your [ternary syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
`condition ? value if true : value if false`
```

you are missing the
`: value if false` portion

## What you probably want is:

```
`:class="isBlue ? 'cube--blue' : 'cube--green'"
```

## Lastly

Now that I've written this out I sort of feel like I should recommend a different approach. Assuming that this cube is either green OR blue, but never both at the same time, you might want to combine the logic into a single step. Perhaps you want to use a conditional inside of a getColor function? This is particularly smart if you will ever have more than two colors. Then the fn just returns a color and you can interpolate that into your class name like:

```
<div :class="`cube--${color}`"></i>
```

Comment: I think I'm too dumb for this answer, I'm not sure which component those go in.

Comment: @fencepencil I added some context for you, and think I found the main issue. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what do you mean by 'or'.

By looking at your data just type:

```
<div class="cube" :class="{ 'cube--blue': isBlue, 'cube--green': isGreen }">
```

---

Update:
Kraken meant to change you approach to:

```
<div class="cube" :class="`cube--${getColor}`">
```

and in your data just type:

```
data() {
  return {
    color: 'blue',
  };
},
computed: {
  getColor() {
    return this.color;
  },
},
```

With this approach you prepare yourself for maybe more colors in the future. By just updating `this.color`.

Comment: This works in the same component, but what about on another component, trying to set `isBlue`. It doesn't recognize there is anything there because it simply sees `<cube-hover></cube-hover>` which is the main component.

Comment: I don't get what trouble you have but maybe Try to send a class name to child by props. And in parent component just do the logic which classes you want.. Can you supply some more code? The best would be jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for the assistance on this man, I'm pullin out my fruckin hair! http://jsfiddle.net/fencepencil/eywraw8t/473028/

Comment: So jsfiddle doesn't allow import/export components but in vscode, I have everything separated. I have a `Page.vue` and a `Cube.vue`. In `Page.vue` I just add `<cube-hover></cube-hover>` but the actual dynamic style is beneath that, in a child element, like 3 divs below ... I don't know how to target that child and change the class on it for each `PageX.vue`.

Comment: I realize I could just create a `BlueCube.vue` and a `GreenCube.vue` but that just seems ridiculous lol

Answer (score 0):

```
<li
   v-for="item in items"
   :key="item.id"
   class="nav-item"
   :class="{ dropdown: hasChildren(item.children) }"
 >
   
 methods: {
    hasChildren(item) {
      return item.length > 0 ? true : false;
    },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to solve this problem.

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
  <div :class="[isInsurancePictureRequired === 'yes' ? 'custom-checkbox-active' : '', 'custom-checkbox']">
      <label class="pic-required-checkbox-label" for="yes">
     <input type="radio" id="yes" name="picture-require" value="yes" @click="handleCheckBox" checked>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
     Yes
  </label>
</div>
```